# Unable to fetch saved images in nodejs / express

Tags: node.js, image, express, mean-stack

I save some images at location `myproject/controllers/upload` and in my `app.js` I mentioned `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/controllers/upload'));` However when I am referring to the image in browser (direct hit) like -

```
http://localhost:3352/controllers/upload/profile_53ce49af9f5ae78d1db89876_img1.jpeg
```

I am unable to get any image, and throwing error -

> Error: ENOENT, stat '/MYROOTDIR/prj/interface/generated/index.html'

Let me know what I am doing wrong here if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..I solved the problem on my own.

Following is the thing that worked for me and now I am able to fetch images from the upload folder.

`app.use('/controllers/upload', express.static(__dirname + "/controllers/upload"));`

One More thing to add -

If you feel to hide your current folder structure you can rename it too like -

> app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/controllers/upload"));

Now the benefit is that you don't need to refer like this -

```
http://localhost:3352/controllers/upload/profile_53ce49af9f5ae78d1db89876_img1.jpeg
```

But -

```
http://localhost:3352/public/profile_53ce49af9f5ae78d1db89876_img1.jpeg
```